# 401 unauthorized fetch API with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api, fetch-api, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am trying to integrate tom-select.js (a selectize non-jquery fork) into my laravel livewire app. Everything is working great except for the create hook - when I try to run a post function to an api controller method, I get a 401 unauthorized response.

If this is not a good way to do it, I'm open to any and all suggestions.  Same-site api authentication is not my strong suite - I've done it with bearer tokens for external apps many times but not sure if everything is configured correctly for same site.

Here's the code(some stuff is hardcoded for testing):

```
                            <div wire:ignore class="">
                            <x-search-select wire:model="part.classification_id" id="classification_id"
                                             name="part.classification_id" label="Classification" placeholder="None">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                @foreach($classifications as $classification)
                                    <option value="{{$classification->id}}">{{$classification->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </x-search-select>

                            <script>
                                fetch("/api/dd", {
                                    method: "GET",
                                    credentials: "same-origin",

                                })
                                new TomSelect('#classification_id', {
                                    plugins: {
                                        remove_button: {
                                            title: 'Remove this item',
                                        }
                                    },
                                    create: function(input,callback){
                                        let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
                                        console.log([token, input]);
                                        let dd_model='part.classification';
                                        fetch("/api/dd", {
                                            headers: {
                                                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                                "Accept": "application/json, text-plain, */*",
                                                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                                                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
                                            },
                                            method: "POST",
                                            credentials: "same-origin",
                                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                                model: dd_model,
                                                name: input,
                                            })
                                        })
                                        .then(function(response){
                                            return response.json();
                                        })
                                            .then (function(json){
                                                console.log(json);
                                            })
                                        .catch(error => console.error(error));

                                        callback({value:input,text:input});
                                    },
                                });
                            </script>
```

Here is the controller method:

```
    public function store(DropdownRequest $request)
{
    $existingRecord = Dropdown::withTrashed()
        ->where('model','=',$request->get('model'))
        ->where('name','=',$request->get('name'))
        ->first();
    if(!$existingRecord){
        $code = $this->dropdown->addItem($request);
    } else {
        $existingRecord->restore();
        $code = $existingRecord;
    }

    return response()->json(['name' => $code->name, 'id' => $code->id], 200);
}
```

and here is the route in routes/api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/dd', [\App\Http\Controllers\DropdownAPIController::class, 'store'])->name('dd-add');
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm a bit confused by the Laravel documentation.  I'm looking to do this without bearer tokens and it says it should be able to do cookie authentication?  Not sure how to proceed.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Authorization` header with the token?

Comment: "Authorization": token in the header of the request

Answer (score 0):

So apparently you can just use web.php with its auth:sanctum middleware and it works like a champ.  I was trying to define the route in api.php which appears to require bearer tokens.